# Error while placing labels within polygons using ArcGIS JS API and external Geometry Service

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, geometry-service

I have published in my ArcGIS Server a map service with a table containing the polygons of all countries on Earth. So this table contains more than 200 rows and the geometry field is of type  `type: esriFieldTypeGeometry , alias: Shape`.

What I would like to do is creating a label inside this polygon, so what I did was modifying this ESRI example ([Create points for labeling](http://resources.esri.com/help/9.3/arcgisserver/apis/javascript/arcgis/help/jssamples_start.htm#jssamples/util_label_point.html)) that, instead of allowing the user drawing a polygon to be sent to the **external Geometry Service**, expects a click from user's side, retrieves clicked-country geometry with a Query operations and draws a predefined label on the country. Of course, last step is not done yet, but this would be the idea.

The problem is that after building a new `Graphic` object with the new geometry retrieved from the layer and call ESRI Geometry Service as in the example, I got an error on Firebug like this:

```
TypeError: _c94 is undefined
...eateSegments:function(_764){_764.shape.path=_764.vmlPath;_764.segmented=false;_7...
```

And well, I don't know why is this happening as **error is not verbose** at all. I noticed that the error is caused by:

```
http://serverapi.arcgisonline.com/jsapi/arcgis/?v=3.2 (On Line 34)
```

So these are my doubts:

- The ESRI example comes, out of the box, with the 1.6 version of ArcGIS JS API. And I changed it to 3.2, because if not, I got this error just when starting the application **because I imported the Feature Layer with dojo.require**:

  "NetworkError: 404 Not Found - [http://serverapi.arcgisonline.com/jsapi/arcgis/1.6/js/esri/layers/FeatureLayer.xd.js"](http://serverapi.arcgisonline.com/jsapi/arcgis/1.6/js/esri/layers/FeatureLayer.xd.js%22)
  uncaught exception: Could not load cross-domain resources: esri.layers.FeatureLayer
- Is it possible that I need a proxy to pass the country geometry to Geometry Server?

I mean, if you check the following image, you can see that there are about 2800 rings. **I am not sure if these data are sent to the geometry service**, but if so, I guess that the **GET request will be huge** and therefore, a proxy should be involved, isn't it?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this sample: ([Create points for labeling (3.2 version)](http://help.arcgis.com/en/webapi/javascript/arcgis/help/jssamples_start.htm#jssamples/util_label_point.html)). According to the error, I guess you were using old method in JS API 1.6, but required the new version of the dojo library. Howerver this JS file: http://serverapi.arcgisonline.com/jsapi/arcgis/1.6/js/esri/layers/FeatureLayer.xd.js
doesn't exist anymore. In the mean time, you can't direct import cross-domain js.

Comment: Yes I think it was the proxy...unfortunately, due to security reasons in my company I can't test it properly, so I will go for something else...Thanks for the tip.